# XML Parsing goes to EXC_BAD_ACCESS code 1 address 0x10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, memory-management, xml-parsing

So here is the thing. I am trying to build **no-ARC/no-Storyboard** project without previous experience in manual memory-management.
Full source code available [here](https://github.com/Fenkins/Products).
So what I've got here is a

### class, which helps me create Products object with custom initialiser

### Products.h

```
@interface Products : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *productName;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *productDescription;
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *productImage;

-(id) initWithName: (NSString *) name
       description: (NSString *) description
             image: (NSString *) image;

@end
```

### Products.m

```
@implementation Products

-(id) initWithName:(NSString *)name description:(NSString *)description image:(NSString *)image {
self = [super init];

if (self) {
    self.productName = name;
    self.productDescription = description;
    self.productImage = image;
}
return self;

@end
```

### There you can see ProductParser class, which one contains most of magic

### ProductsParser.h

```
@interface ProductsParser : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>

@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *productArray;

-(id) initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *) productArray;
-(void) parseXMLFile;

@end
```

### ProductParser.m

```
    // Creating private properties
@interface ProductsParser()
@property NSXMLParser *parser;
@property NSString *element;

@property NSMutableString *currentProductName;
@property NSMutableString *currentProductDescription;
@property NSMutableString *currentProductImage;

@end



@implementation ProductsParser
-(id) initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)productArray {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.productArray = productArray;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) parseXMLFile {
    // We will do it here instead of writing that in viewDidLoad
    NSURL *xmlPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]URLForResource:@"productsList" withExtension:@"xml" ];
    self.parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:xmlPath];
    self.parser.delegate = self;
    [self.parser parse];
    [self.parser release];
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    self.element = elementName;
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@""];
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"  " withString:@""];

    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"Name"]) {
        if (self.currentProductName == nil) {
            self.currentProductName = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
        } else {
            [self.currentProductName appendString:string];
        }
    }
    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"Description"]) {
        if (self.currentProductDescription == nil) {
            self.currentProductDescription = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
        } else {
            [self.currentProductDescription appendString:string];
        }
    }    if ([self.element isEqualToString:@"Image"]) {
        if (self.currentProductImage == nil) {
            self.currentProductImage = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
        } else {
            [self.currentProductImage appendString:string];
        }
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Product"]) {
        Products *thisProduct = [[Products alloc] initWithName:self.currentProductName description:self.currentProductDescription image:self.currentProductImage];

        [self.productArray addObject:thisProduct];


        [self.currentProductName release];
        self.currentProductName = nil;


        [self.currentProductDescription release];
        self.currentProductDescription = nil;


        [self.currentProductImage release];
        self.currentProductImage = nil;


        [thisProduct release];
        thisProduct = nil;


        [self.element release];
        self.element = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

### Later on, in the class which is suppose to handle the UITableView I am creating:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *productArray;
```

### And In viewDidLoad we have this code

```
self.productArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
ProductsParser *menuParser = [[ProductsParser alloc] initWithArray:self.productArray];
[menuParser parseXMLFile];
[menuParser release];
```

All that results in EXC_BAD_ACCESS pointing to

```
@property (nonatomic,retain)NSString *productName;
```

I've done some research about that error. Users claims that they successfully getting rid of that error by simply calling properties with self. syntax.(which is suppose to increase retain count?) In my case it is not the issue, as you may see.(Or did I missed something?)

I am also can see in debugger that productArray which is suppose to be populated with my products from .xml file, is in fact populated by trash stuff like @"/n/t" @"/n     " @"/n/t" and so on.(why why why?!)

So at least point it to me, where to start. Really appreciate your guys help.

**UPDATE 1**: Apparently there was some defect logic, I almost got rid of the \n\t stuff by changing code in foundCharacters section.
So now instead of just \n\t \n \n\t I got actual data in my array with those afterwards. Like so:

```
@"Box of chocolate \n\t\t"
@"Box of chocolate, very tasty \n"
@"ImageName \n\t"
```

I know that \n should be like new line, and \t is apparently tabulation. Still, don't have a clear idea on how to completely get rid of those and why are they popping up.

**UPDATE 2**: I manage to get rid of the trashy \n\t from the array by adding stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. (code updated)

Comment: did you try to change `retain` into `strong`?

Comment: @nghia-luong Sorry for inconvenience from my side, did I have to change property (retain,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *productArray; Line to property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *productArray; ? If so, this one do change something, I even got array populated with 2 objects on one of the runs, but program ends with the same BAD_ACCESS error everytime. Also array keep getting populated by trashy items, not the one it intends to.

Comment: no, I means `@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *productName;`, or did you check `self.currentProductName = string;`, `string` that you passed just not really type is `NSString`. Help this might help

Comment: @nghia-luong done-did that, so now it runs without ugly exception! But array is still populating with at"\n\t\t" at"\n" at"\n\t" and so on... Any thoughts on that? I also added few releases: one after [menuParser parseXMLFile]; and one just before [self.element = nil];